# git interactive rebase (reword) failure - changes order, loses commits

Tags: git, rebase

I wanted to rename the third latest commit and add 5 characters using `git rebase`, but the result was a total failure.
The order changes and some commits seems to be skipped.

I do the command: `git rebase -i HEAD~5`
Then the vim editor opens and shows a few commits with the word "pick" to the left.
There is already a problem here - the commits aren't chronological, the order is wrong.
It does include the commit I wanted to change. But the first two commits are from 4th september, the next 2 are from 24th august (way back), and the 5th one (which I wanted to change) is from 5th september.

I change "pick" into "reword" at the commit I want to change, then save and exit with `wq`.
After that the editor doesn't open again to let me edit the commit message. Instead it says

```
"interactive rebase in progress; onto 23lkj4
last commands done (4 commands done): 
pick 234lkj (some message)
reword 53k2k3(some long message)
no commands remaining.
(some more info)
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution¨
(some more info)
Could not apply 53k2k3... (long commit message)
```

So it failed to do the "reword".
Then I can do `git rebase --continue.`

To illustrate how the result turn out, I have an example list of commits here, which would be the result of doing `git log --oneline` **before** the rebase, where the latest commit is the top one. To the right of each commit I have added the order it gets **after** doing the rebase and doing `git log --oneline`. So "1" is the top one (latest)

```
(original commit log list)                                            resulting order after rebase

kjh23h Merge branch 'something' into 'something'                             gone?
23mk54 some commit with a a long commit message , from 5th september         1
13w354 some commit with a a long commit message                              gone?
6224nj  Merged in some branch                                                gone?
175234nj  Merged in some branch                                              4
45234nj  Merged in some branch                                               5

(21 more commits)                                                            6,7,8,etc

4782hjs some commit from 24th august                                         2
98234jd some commit from 24th august                                         3
(other commits)
```

How can it go so wrong, and what may be the problem?

Comment: Instead of `git log --oneline` say `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`. Show the output in your question.

Comment: Note that by default merge commits do not appear in rebase list. So nothing "wrong" about that.

Comment: Also show us only real output including real SHA values. Otherwise we just assume you are not describing the output correctly.

Comment: @matt How would you inspect the real SHA values, how does it relate to the problem?  The example list I made is based on the real one, it is a list which has merge commits and regular commits. The real commit messages has a lot of info but why would that be relevant?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is your understanding of how Git is expected to function. Basically, you should read some docs (carefully), and/or tutorials on the basic operation. An interactive rebase is quite basic, although not one of the most basic operations possible like "git init / clone / commit / checkout"

I will point the specific misconceptions demonstrated in your question:

1. The "to-do" list that Git presents as the "--interactive" is a list of commits in ancestry order, earliest (by ancestry relationship, ie, parent-child) first. Chronology doesn't matter **at all**. Whatever remains in this "to-do" recipe is what Git will do, in that exact order, when you save it.
2. It wasn't the "rewording" that failed, but the fact that the commit is **empty** and would not be committed at all, hence no need to reword. Some of the info you deleted tells you what to do if you want to keep the empty commit, which will allow you to add an empty commit, and reword the commit message.

If that commit is empty now, it's because one or two merge commits were dropped as [documented in the manpage](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--r), which explains why you used `HEAD~5` instead of `HEAD~3` which would be the precise reference needed to reword the "*3rd latest commit*".

The commit you're looking to reword only removed content added by the merged branch. Since the merge was dropped, there is nothing to remove, hence the empty commit, hence the rewording having become unnecessary. If you intended to keep the content from the merged branch, and only justify removing part of it in the commit you're looking to reword, you should have used `--rebase-merges` as the manual explains.

You could have rebased on `HEAD~3`; the merges would not have been considered, and therefore not dropped, the reword would have worked as you expected, unless `HEAD~2` or `HEAD` are also merges, in which case they would have been dropped (unexpectedly by you).

**How can it go so wrong?**

What a great question. The answer is that something **fundamental** is wrong. Not reading the instructions on the screen, or the [man-page for `rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) are the **fundamental** issues.